# Should [typescript3.0] be renamed to [typescript3.x]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I almost created a tag for "Typescript 3.4" until I noticed that [typescript3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript3.0)'s description states:

> Tag for questions specific to new features in TypeScript 3.x.

Why is that so?

I feel like this tag should be renamed to [typescript3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript3.x) just like how Python has a [python-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x) tag, and the [typescript3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript3.0) tag should be reserved for questions about Typescript 3.0 features.

Thoughts?

Comment: Version tags are annoying for, amongst other reasons, *this* particular case.  But I do wonder if there's any ambiguity between using a typescript3.0 tag over a typescript 3.x tag.  Like...does it really *gain* us anything?

Comment: I would recommend [[tag:typescript3]] over [[tag:typescript3.x]]. No need for the *x* if you're referring to the major version number.

Comment: @Makoto It would be useful to have a tag (typescript3.0) specifically for features in 3.0 and tag for features in major version 3. The gain is that you can discriminate between issues in a minor versions of TS

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not necessarily opposed, though I'm used to seeing a `.x` to signify  a minor version wildcard.

Comment: Are there significant issues arising *only* in minor versions that need version-specific tags?

Comment: @CodyGray Well, issues / questions and clarification. I was about to post a question about "`const` assertions," which were introduced in Typescript 3.4 until I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55230653/whats-the-difference-between-typescript-const-assertions-and-declarations) related question. Someone who frequents that tag more often than I could better answer your question

Comment: @pushin yeah but who cares that it was introduced in typescript 3.4. That is something for release notes, not for tags on Stack Overflow. We're not documenting when features were introduced here, the only purpose of a tag is to create a logical distinction between conflicting elements. Like - differentiating versions, usually major versions, in which behavior has radically changed to the point where it is valuable to know the more precise version to be able to answer a question without having to verify it.

Comment: One problem is that [TypeScript does not use semver](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14116), so breaking changes can (and have) come in minor versions. I'm not saying we *need* a tag for every major version, just that it could be necessary.

Comment: Rename it to [[typescript3.3.3333](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript/v/3.3.3333)].

Comment: @CodyGray For python we do use [python-3.x] (with various other tag synonyms including [python3]) https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python-3.x/info

Comment: But python is quite a special case, like Angular or Angular2, or the C++ of the nineties and the current C++. I wouldn't be too much in favor of  version tag unless there is a real huge non-backward compatible difference.

Comment: @HereticMonkey this is painfully obvious when your stumbling across https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/releases/tag/v3.3.3333

Comment: @DavidSherret or 3.3.4000 ;)

Comment: @Mafii I was thinking that HereticMonkey was writing that as jest... I think tag version for TypeScript are meaningless.

Comment: Do the version numbers really matter though? Is the tag `[typescript]` and a mentioning inside the question itself that it uses `typescriptX.Y` not enough?

Answer (score 6):

I will leave [this here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14116):

> The trade-off for getting millions of dollars of engineering investment in the TypeScript project is that marketing gets to control version numbers to a certain extent.
>
> It's not really an unalloyed good anyway. If we followed semver rules exactly, literally every single release would be a major version bump. Any time we produced the wrong type or emitted the wrong code or failed to issue a correct error, that's a breaking change, and we fix dozens of bugs like that in every release. The middle digit just isn't useful for TypeScript in a strict semver interpretation.

If marketing, not developers, have control of the version numbers in any way/form, there's no guarantee that the public API will be stable in either x.y.* versions or *.*.* versions. For typescript, versions are meaningless.

Comment: Ok, so is your vote for dropping the minor version and retagging as Typescript3, or is it for doing nothing?

Comment: @pushkin I'm just noting something I've noted several times before, but in this case the very developer explicitly tell everyone so: versions are meaningless.